# How to retrieve parameters from mavlink .tlog using pymavlink?

Tags: python, ardupilot

I've been able to use [pymavlink.mavutil](https://github.com/mavlink/pymavlink/blob/master/mavutil.py) to read telemetry from a .tlog created by [MissionPlanner](https://github.com/diydrones/MissionPlanner).

To do this, I create a `mavlogfile` like this:

`mlog = mavutil.mavlink_connection('mylogfile.tlog')`

Now I want to read the flight parameters (settings) from the .tlog . The method mavlogfile.param_fetch_all() appears to be designed only to work with a live telemetry link rather than a log. It sends a parameter request command, which obviously has no result when you are linked to a log rather than an actual aircraft.

I know the parameters are in the .tlog... how do I get them out?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's implemented in https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink/blob/master/pymavlink/tools/mavparms.py

and the relevant code is:

`m = mlog.recv_match(type='PARAM_VALUE')`